# Argument of type 'HTMLFormElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ElementRef<any>'

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm working with angular and creating a form element.

I have this inside **app.component.html**,

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f></form>
```

And this inside **app.component.ts**,

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    onSubmit(form: ElementRef){
        alert('ss');
    }
}
```

But getting this error.

> src/app/app.component.html:16:34 - error TS2345: Argument of type
> 'HTMLFormElement' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'ElementRef'.   Property 'nativeElement' is missing in type
> 'HTMLFormElement' but required in type 'ElementRef'.
>
> 16       <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it like this. According to the [Angular NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm), you can try like :

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  ...
</form>
```

```js
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
...

onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
  console.log(f.value);
  console.log(f.valid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It will great help if you can tell why previous one not working :(

Comment: Well, that's a good question. I'm not sure, but I think the `ngForm` is a directive who will allow you to use it as FormGroup. Otherwise, with `HTMLElement` or `ElementRef`, you will only have access to the HTML element, and not methods like `addControl()`, `getControl()`, etc ...